# Postgres 9.3 - Problem to initialize folder as a data folder

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have a problem when I want to initialize a folder as a data folder:

```
postgres@ccruzado-test01:~$ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/initdb -D /datadrive/postgresql/
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.UTF-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

creating directory /datadrive/postgresql ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in /datadrive/postgresql/base/1 ... LOG:  could not link file "pg_xlog/xlogtemp.1716" to "pg_xlog/000000010000000000000001" (initialization of log file): Operation not supported
FATAL:  could not open file "pg_xlog/000000010000000000000001": No such file or directory
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing data directory "/datadrive/postgresql"
```

The directory /datadrive/postgresql/ is a drive mounted by CIFS in FSTAB

```
//prueba /datadrive cifs vers=2.1,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,nounix 0 0.
```

The OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What OS are you on? What are the mount options for your CIFS share?

Comment: Ububtu 14.04, I mount the drive with this command in FSTAB: //prueba /datadrive cifs vers=2.1,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,nounix 0 0. I edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the data directory on Linux includes creating hard links, which is not supported on CIFS shares. This is why the creation is failing.

It's usually not a good idea to create data stores / clusters on remote shares, it might lead to issues if the share disappears in the middle of using it.

Comment: ok, so it's not possible :(, do you have documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1. Check the *uid* and *gid* of the *postgres* user

   ```
   bash-4.2$ id postgres

   uid=1001(postgres) gid=1001(postgres) groups=1001(postgres)
   ```
2. *dir_mode* and *file_mode* should be 0700 while mounting.

   Give the *uid* and *gid* parameter while mounting, e.g.:

   ```
   bash-4.2$ mount.cifs -o username=NASUser,password=NAS_PASSWORD,dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0700,gid=1001,uid=1001 //IP/PATH  MountPath
   ```